# Read and map property file without Spring

Tags: java, spring, properties, jackson, properties-file

I have a `property.yaml` file:

```
table:
  map:
    0:
      - 1
      - 2
      - 3
    1:
      - 1
      - 2
      - 3
      - 4
    2:
      - 1
      - 2
      - 3
    3:
      - 1
      - 2
      - 3
```

I want to map it to `Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map`. It's easy task with `@ConfigurationProperties("table")`. But I have to do it without `Spring`. Any idea?

Comment: Use a YAML library.

Answer (score 4):

Spring uses *snakeyaml* so it is already on your classpath, you can use it out of the box. The project page is [here](https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/src/master/) if you need more info.

In your case you can do something like this:

```java
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(Yourclass.class, new LoaderOptions()));
Yourclass yc = (Yourclass) yaml.load(yourfile);
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = yc.map;
```

***Useful references***:

- [Parsing YAML with SnakeYAML](https://www.baeldung.com/java-snake-yaml)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Adam Arold for help. Solution:

**FileProperties.class**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class FileProperties {
    private Map<String, List<String>> table;
}
```

**MyClass**

```
public class MyClass {
    public FileProperties readYaml(String filename) {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        InputStream inputStream = this.getClass()
                .getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream(filename);
        return yaml.load(inputStream);
    }
```

yaml

```
!!com.test.test.FileProperties
table:
  key1:
    - value1
    - value12
    - value13
  key2:
    - value11
    - value12
    - value15
  key3:
    - value11
    - value12
    - value15
```

Note the `!!com.test.test.FileProperties` holds the info about the class to be used when loading it.